# PHP shell_exec выполнение консольной команды

Tags: php

Пытаюсь написать выполнение консольной команды после нажатия на кнопку. Вот что получилось

```
<tr class="method1">
        <th style="color: #831623" scope="row">record</th>
        <td>
            <button id="recordStart" name="record">start</button>
            <?php
                $output = shell_exec($_POST['ffmpeg -i udp://@239.239.2.1:1234 -vcodec copy -an -r 25 -t 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 video_for_test.mp4']);
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

к сожалению это не работает. В чем причина, так и не могу понять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел то что мне нужно.

я сделал это немного проще чем ваше решение, единственное что еще не подключил, это то, что выдает ffmpeg "2>&1"

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="recordStart" value="start" />
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['recordStart'])){
   $output = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i <input_файл> -vcodec copy -an -t <время_записи> -r <FPS> -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 <output_файл>.mp4');
   }
?>
</form>
```

Единственное что не сделано, `2>&1` это то что выдает FFMPEG

Answer (score 0):

PHP, скорее всего, отрабатывает и возвращает результат выполнения команды. Но на этом всё заканчивается, хотя ffmpeg продолжает работать.
Нужно зациклить чтение шелла, примерно так (Найдено на ENSO):

```
<?php
function liveExecuteCommand($cmd)
{

    while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

    $proc = popen("$cmd 2>&1 ; echo Exit status : $?", 'r');

    $live_output     = "";
    $complete_output = "";

    while (!feof($proc))
    {
        $live_output     = fread($proc, 4096);
        $complete_output = $complete_output . $live_output;
        echo "$live_output";
        @ flush();
    }

    pclose($proc);

    // get exit status
    preg_match('/[0-9]+$/', $complete_output, $matches);

    // return exit status and intended output
    return array (
                    'exit_status'  => $matches[0],
                    'output'       => str_replace("Exit status : " . $matches[0], '', $complete_output)
                 );
}
?>
```

Пример использования:

```
$result = liveExecuteCommand('ls -la');

if($result['exit_status'] === "0"){
   // do something if command execution succeeds
} else {
    // do something on failure
}
```

Оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107147/php-reading-shell-exec-live-output

Comment: Если бы ffmpeg продолжал дальше работать, у меня бы создался файл в папке

Comment: а что там php отрабатывает-то? $_POST['ffmpeg...]? откуда оно вообще возьмется? и куда пойдет этот $output... там вообще сюрр какой-то в вопросе

Comment: $cmd = 'ffmpeg -i SAMPLE.AVI 2>&1';

exec($cmd, $output, $value);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($value);
var_dump($cmd);
exit; Код проверил. Работает. Взял в соседней теме на ruSO

Comment: @AlexandrBlinov не могли бы написать доп. ответ и немного объяснить эту команду.

Answer (score 0):

Я проверял так:

```
<?php
$cmd = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/drop.avi -r 10 -s 100x200 /home/apache/out.avi'; - В переменную добавляем команду для exec. Взять файл drop и сконвертировать в out.avi
$out=exec($cmd, $output, $value); - Собственно, выполняем команду.
var_dump($output); - Смотрим что исполненая команда дала на выход.
var_dump($value); - Статус завершения - это результат выполнения приложения, т.е. с каким кодом он завершил работу. Если 0 - то всё хорошо. Если НЕ 0 - значит завершился с ошибкой.
var_dump($cmd); - На всякий случай выводим использованную команду.
exit;
?>
```

При успешном выполнении должны получить что-то вроде :

```
array(0) { } int(0) string(72) "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/drop.avi -r 10 -s 100x200 /home/apache/out2.avi"
```

Comment: @Insider Самая популярная проблема, кстати, с указанием ПОЛНОГО пути к ffmpeg и правами у пользователя apache на запись файла.

Comment: Права у пользователя я сменил, и могу делать через PHP все что захожу. Но мои знания PHP... это очень начальный уровень.

Comment: Так. Давайте начнем с простого. Вы уверены что ffmpeg установлен? Проверьте полный путь до него командой в консоли #which ffmpeg. После этого скиньте результат выполнения моего кода в браузере, естесственно с подстановкой своего input файла и out-файлом в директории, куда apache (Ну или nginx, я ж не знаю что за сервер Вами используется) имеет права на доступ.

Comment: поверьте у меня все установлено и работает. У вас ведь выполняется просто php код, нет нажатия кнопки которое собственно мне нужно. Так же ffmpeg, не выдает обычный stdout - а stderror.